# Event.preventDefault() and check boxes in form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form being sent over ajax with event.preventdefault on it so it doesn't send automatically but this then stops the check boxes from functioning...
How do I get around this...
[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QYz2X/1/)

```
$('[name="id"]').each(function (index, el) {
  var getval = $(this).val();
  console.log(getval);
  $('#form_pub_priv_' + getval).on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var arr_unchecked_values = $('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').map(function () {
      return this.value;
    }).get();
    var formvalues = $('#form_pub_priv_' + getval + ' [name="id"]').serialize();
    var dataJoin = '&mod=' + arr_unchecked_values + '&' + formvalues;
    console.log(dataJoin);
    $.ajax({
      url: 'unpublish-Lyst.html',
      type: 'POST',
      data: dataJoin
    })
    .done(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .fail(function () {
      console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function () {
      console.log("complete");
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: The form won't submit just because a checkbox is clicked.

Comment: Not really my question...

Comment: The point is that there's no need to call `.preventDefault()`.  Clicking the checkbox or the form will not cause it to submit, so there's no reason to prevent the default action of the "click" - which is to make the checkboxes work properly.

Comment: yes makes perfect sense!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're stopping the `click` event indirectly in your checkboxes, that's why your checkboxes don't work.

```
  $('#form_pub_priv_' + getval).on('click', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();   //Remove this!
      var arr_unchecked_values = ...
```

To prevent the form from being submited, you should do it in tye `submit` form event.

```
  $('#form_pub_priv_' + getval).submit(function(event){
      ...
      event.preventDefault(); //Here it's ok
  });
```

Cheers

Comment: Ok my problem still arrises as sson as i turn on the css: http://jsfiddle.net/QYz2X/5/
If i remove the event default it submits both the top form as the one I'm clicking??

Comment: Don't worry, it happens :). Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia